# Angular 2 CanLoad failure causes blank page

Tags: angular, routes

Let's say I have a route with `canLoad` protected with some `AuthGuard`.

```
{
    path: 'cabinet',
    loadChildren: './modules/cabinet/cabinet.module#CabinetModule',
    // canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard]
},
```

There's a redirect in AuthGuard:

```
canLoad(route: Route): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {    
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    return false;
}
```

When I navigate to the rout directly by url I get redirected to the home page but nothing is displayed there, just a blank screen.

When I remove `canLoad` everything works fine: I'm redirected to the home page and it's not blank.

`canActivate` and `canActivateChild` are the same as `canLoad` in code.

Can I achieve proper redirect using `canLoad`? Or maybe I misuse it?

There isn't any error in console.